Combining Multiple 'where' Conditions with Timestamps in a Firestore Query in Flutter
I want to retrieve documents from a Firestore collection in Flutter that match a specific list of IDs and have an updated date newer than the cached date stored on my device.
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await collection
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: documentIDs)
        .where('updatedDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: cachedDate)
        .get();

Error Message

Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/invalid-argument] Client specified an invalid argument. Note that this differs from failed-precondition. invalid-argument indicates arguments that are problematic regardless of the state of the system (e.g., an invalid field name).)

I have verified that each where condition works correctly individually. The problem only arises when I use both where conditions together. How can I solve this problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So you say that you get that error only when you combine those where calls?

Yes, it works fine when I use the "where" conditions separately. I can fetch a specific list of documents or make a date-based query. However, the two do not work together.

Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and please also show us the content of your documentIDs list.

It's seems like is all about index types in Firestore. The documentation says

Cloud Firestore uses composite indexes to support compound queries not already supported by single-field indexes. For example, you would need a composite index for the following queries

citiesRef.where("country", "in", ["USA", "Japan", "China"])
         .where("population", ">", 690000)

Here you can find more details:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#queries_supported_by_composite_indexes

Unfortunately, it appears that Flutter does not support these types of queries natively. Nevertheless, I appreciate your help and the information you provided.
I created two different collection for different document groups. It will work until I find a better solution.
